# Why rop2 16 and rop3 256 ? does the 2^(2^2) and 2^(2^3) really make sense?

Tags: raster, graphic

I'm reading a book about windows graphics programming.

When comes about rop2 and rop3 , it gives 2^(2^2)=16 and 2^(2^3)=256,but why?

Anybody knows? thanks in advance!

Comment: Where is `rop2` or `rop3` defined? I can't see anything online about them.

Comment: Sorry but I can't find a wiki about it either, it's kind of mix two or three pixel , with and , or , not , xor .

Answer (score 2):

For GDI ROP2, it is not to hard to understand.
The definition can be found at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc234985.aspx.

A better explanation can be found at http://www.svgopen.org/2003/papers/RasterOperationsUsingFilterElements/.
Only 4 bits are used to get the results. So in total 2^4 = 16 operations.

For ROP3, there is one more combination, 8 bits are used. In total, there are 2^8 = 256 possible operations.

Comment: Hi jiulun,
   Thanks so much for your answer, they're of great help, but I still didn't quite catch the answer to my question.
   As is documented, we got 16 ROP2s and 256 ROP3s, but it seems that 16 and 256 are not from pure 2^x (x=4 or ).
   For example,each of A,B and C has two different values, if we want to get one value from each of them, the combination is 2*2*2 == 2^3 == 8, by which I mean we get 2^x first, and then the total number.

Comment: But for ROP2 and ROP3, I can't get 2^x first , I just think we get 16 or 256 operations first, they happen to be 2^4 or 2^8, and then we want to compute them easily so we define P=1100 D=1010 and get 2^4 in the end.

Comment: I can't explain 2^4 and 2^8 the way I explain 2^3 in the example above. For ROP2, I know that there's P and ~P for P, and D,~D for D, and then? what's next? 'and or xor'? but how about black and white?I got confused.....